# `dplyr::if_else()` compared to base R `ifelse()` - why rbindlist error?

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, flextable

This code block below utilizing `dplyr::if_else()` works without issue and produces the flextable shown.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(flextable)

# utilizing dplyr if_else
df1 <- tibble(col1 = c(5, 2), col2 = c(6, 4)) %>% 
  mutate(col3 = if_else(apply(.[, 1:2], 1, sum) > 10 & .[, 2] > 5, 
                        "True",
                        "False"))
df1 %>% flextable() %>% theme_zebra()
```

[image: table]

I first tried this with base R `ifelse()` and got the error shown below. The error doesn't seem to make any sense. Can somebody explain? My data frame doesn't have anywhere near 15 columns.

```
# utilizing base R ifelse
df2 <- tibble(col1 = c(5, 2), col2 = c(6, 4)) %>% 
  mutate(col3 = ifelse(apply(.[, 1:2], 1, sum) > 10 & .[, 2] > 5, 
                        "True",
                        "False"))
df2 %>% flextable() %>% theme_zebra()

# Error in rbindlist(x$content$data) : 
  # Item 5 has 15 columns, inconsistent with item 1 which has 14 columns. 
  # To fill missing columns use fill=TRUE.
```

Comment: What happens if you ran the base `ifelse` with `fill=TRUE`?

Comment: If I append `, fill = TRUE` after `"False"` I still get the same error. Even if that worked I'm curious as to what's happening.

Comment: Have you checked if one of your variables or functions were masked/overwritten? Try to clear your global environment, for me the code works fine

Comment: Take a look at `str(df2)`. You can see that `df2$col3` is a 2x1 `matrix` whereas `df1$col3` is a `chr` vector.

Comment: Furthermore your `dplyr` syntax seems somewhat unusual. Why not do `... + mutate(col3 = if_else(col1 + col2 > 10 & col2 < 5, "True", "False"))`? There's no need for the `apply` call with `MARGIN = 1` here since operations are already vectorised by row.

Comment: Didn't take that approach because my column names in imported data often change, although their relative positions stay the same. I'll expand on this in my next stackoverflow question coming soon.

Comment: @JasonHunter I'd still advise against using `apply` within a `dplyr`/`tidyr` approach (as you've found out, `apply`-based solutions can lead to [unexpected results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10037745/losing-class-information-when-i-use-apply-in-r) when working on `data.frame`s). If you have multiple (and/or a varying number of) columns a more `tidyverse`-canonical approach would be to reshape from wide to long, then operate on your long data before reshaping back to wide. Looking forward to your next SO question to expand;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a `flextable` expert but after breaking down your problem I observe

```
df <- tibble::tibble(col1 = c(5, 2), col2 = c(6, 4))

ifelse(apply(df[, 1:2], 1, sum) > 10 & df[, 2] > 5, "True", "False")
#     col2   
#[1,] "True" 
#[2,] "False"
```

which is 2 X 1 matrix and

```
dplyr::if_else(apply(df[, 1:2], 1, sum) > 10 & df[, 2] > 5, "True", "False")
#[1] "True"  "False"
```

is a character vector. So if you do

```
df2 <- tibble(col1 = c(5, 2), col2 = c(6, 4)) %>% 
       mutate(col3 = as.character(ifelse(apply(.[, 1:2], 1, sum) > 10 & .[, 2] > 5, 
                   "True", "False")))
```

it works as expected.

Comment: Why does `ifelse()` create a matrix, even though I don't request that? Is it simply a design decision that the `dplyr::if_else()` function chose not to adopt for some presumably good reasons.

Comment: @JasonHunter not exactly sure but can be something related to `if_else` having a strict type checking.

Answer (score 1):

As demonstrated by @ronak-shah, your ifelse is creating a matrix, which does not please `flextable` ;)

You don't need to format the data before using flextable. For example, I would have use `colformat_lgl` there:

```
df2 <- tibble(col1 = c(5, 2), col2 = c(6, 4)) %>% 
  mutate( col3 = rowSums(.) > 10 & col2 > 5 )

flextable(df2) %>% 
  colformat_lgl("col3", true = "True", false = "False")
```